# Why should a method (not) be both accessor and mutator?

Tags: java, conventions, accessor, mutators

Many Java methods in the JDK, such as `List.set()` and `Map.put()` both change an object and return a result instead of keeping mutator and accessor separate.

It seems to me that for most of these methods, the return value is more of a side effect, and it wouldn't make sense to have a separate method to retrieve it.

But apart from this, are there other benefits and drawbacks of each approach? How do I decide which way is more appropriate?

For example, I'm creating a simulator object, calling the `runSimulation()` method, and I need the `boolean` result. I could store it in the simulator object and return it in a separate accessor method called after, or return it in the mutator itself, as I'm doing now.

Comment: Please, give an actual code, and we can figure out your need!

Comment: @ThexPhi If you read the question, you would know that it's a conceptual question.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with a method that does some work (mutating the state of a class) and also returns a value. Storing the value in a field of the class and returning it via a separate method creates additional work both for the class and for its clients and does not bring any benefit whatsoever.

Comment: I reworded the question so that answers are less likely to be primarily opinion-based. If a reviewer reads this, please comment if there's anything else that can be done to "un-hold" this question.

Comment: Prime624624, I just learned that this question is only placed in a "reopen review queue" if it is edited by you within 5 days of being set on hold. So please make any edit to this question (probably rephrase some sentence) to trigger this.

Comment: @JensBannmann Thanks for helping. I'm glad there are a few good users around. I made an edit. Seems pretty petty that rephrasing a question can make it go from closed to open. The content and idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless runSimulation() is a blocking method and you want to run it asynchronously so it doesn't block your main thread, theres no harm in returning the result with the same method you create the simulation with, as long as returning it can be done cheaply.

Sometimes it is a matter of convenience: is the design of your object such that users will almost always be requesting the result after creating/running the simulation? It might be a good idea, then, to return the result in the mutating method (maybe you could name the method "runSimulationForResult()").

Sometimes it's a matter of efficiency: for some kinds of List implementations (LinkedList, etc.), calling get() followed by set() means the list is traversed twice instead of once, and even though it might not be a super common pattern, the designers decided there wasn't any harm in returning the previous value, since it could be achieved practically for free, and would make certain idioms twice as fast.

Comment: I never thought about the List example that way, but it makes sense. In my case, it wouldn't cost any more to return the boolean in a separate method, but the methods would always be called together anyways, so I'll just include it in the mutator.